# Build files name change - files that are generated from create react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

The build files generated through create react app have different names (hash code) every time.

I would like to give custom names for the generated files.

Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without ejecting

Answer (score 4):

You can change the output filename by customizing the `filename` property in webpack config -- refer to https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/

The default implementation is kept like this because, because every time you build an asset, it generates a new name and browsers won't be able to serve a cached response.

If you change the name to a constant you might need to clear the browser cache manually/ disable cache to see your changes immediately. (I think...Applicable only in prod mode as dev mode makes use of Hot module replacement)

Steps to change file name in CRA.

1. `npm run eject` This will unwind the hidden configs from CRA and show some additional config folders
2. Move to the config folder.
3. Edit file webpack.config.js (Somewhere around line 172 - 180 you can see `filename:` section where this is defined)

Comment: Thanks for the response. May I know where I can find that file for application generated with create react app?

Comment: You need to eject the app first. I'll update the answer to do that

Comment: Please note that if you eject the app you will have to start maintaining the webpack configuration yourself and you derive from the standard. https://medium.com/curated-by-versett/dont-eject-your-create-react-app-b123c5247741

Answer (score 0):

Following up to my comment, if you absolutely must change Webpack configuration you can also consider libraries such as:

- [Craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#api)
- [Rescripts](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts)

Comment: craco doesn't have support for adding  __filename to "node" property