# How to change class name generation without eject (using react-app-rewrite, update localIdentName)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, css-modules, react-app-rewired

Using **CRA** (create-react-app) it is possible to use **css-modules** (index.module.css). They generate the standard name `...[name]__[hash]`. It is necessary without using `npm run eject` to change the name template with `react-app-rewired`. Example: `prod-123-[hash]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build files name change - files that are generated from create react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58090904/build-files-name-change-files-that-are-generated-from-create-react-app)

Comment: No, question about css class names (<img class="app_name__hash" />)